# Math Analysis Question on Continuous Functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The Question: Suppose the function  $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x_{0}$ and  $f(x_{0}) > 0$. Prove there is an interval, $I = (x_{0} -\frac{1}{n}, x_{0} + \frac{1}{n} )$ where n is an natural number, such that $f(x) >0$ for all $x \in I$.

The Attempt: (Here is what I have so far)

Let $f$, and $x_0$ be as stated in the problem. Suppose by contradiction that for all natural numbers n, $I = (x_{0} -\frac{1}{n}, x_{0} + \frac{1}{n} )$ contains one element, x which $f(x) \leq 0$. Since $f$ is continuous at $x_{0}$, this means for any sequence, $(x_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (x_{i})_{i=1}^{n} = x_{0}$ implies that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_{i})_{i=1}^{n} = f(x_{0}).$

The thing I am confused on is how to come up with a sequence which includes the x term which $f(x) \leq 0$.

I was thinking at first if $f$ is continuous sequentially, then $f$ is continuous by using $\epsilon -\delta$ criterion. Can you guys give me hints on how to approach this problem? Please try not to work on the problem.

Thank you. I appreciate it.

Comment: All basic real analysis questions have been asked and answered already.

Answer (score 1):

I think your sequence idea is fine. Assume for the sake of contradiction that for any $n$ there exists a $y \in B(1/n,x_0)$ such that $f(y) \leq 0$. Then you get a sequence $(y_n)$ all with $f(y_n) \leq 0$.  Letting $n \to \infty$ we have $y_n \to x_0$ and so $f(y_n) \to f(x_0) \leq 0$; hence a contradiction.

Comment: I guess what I do not understand is where the sequence, $(y_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ comes from. How do you know this sequence is negative?

Comment: Axiom of choice. Since each $I_n = (x_0-1/n,x_0+1/n)$ is non-empty, I can choose an indexed family i.e a sequence $(y_n)$ such that $y_n \in I_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Contradiction is the right idea. Try this: Suppose $f(x_0)\leq 0$. Then let $\epsilon := |\frac{f(x_0)}{2}|$. Since $f$ is continuous, $\exists \delta>0$ such that if $|x-x_0|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<|\dfrac{f(x_0)}{2}|$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yeah. However I am trying to prove this by using sequences. There is a theorem in the book I am using which states that sequential continuity is equivalent to the $\epsilon-\delta$ continuity. Could I say that?

Comment: Yes. They're equivalent so I'm not sure why you need to use sequences. It is certainly doable, as the other answer indicates.